# QuickTime player installation

Tags: software-installation, quicktime

I am trying to install QuickTime Player on Ubuntu. I have done some research on the web regarding this. Many webpages say that we need to install "Restricted Formats" of Ubuntu based on version. I can't understand that.

How can I install QuickTime player on my Ubuntu system?

Comment: You could try installing VLC - it will play all media formats. You can do so by typing `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

Answer (score 7):

*I am not offering a way how to install QuickTime Player but offering alternative ways to play your files. As far as I know, Apple never really offered a Linux version*

## Regarding Installing Restricted Formats

According to the [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats), you can install the restricted formats package via

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

or

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

## Regarding Alternative Players Being Able to Play Files

As @JonasCz already mentioned, VLC might be a good option. You can install it via

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

In addition, there are **smplayer** and **mplayer** which should both be able to play all your files

```
sudo apt install smplayer
```

or for mplayer

```
sudo apt install mplayer
```